# Python struct with large list

Tags: python, struct, data-conversion, pack

Im trying to convert my very long integer list i a binary array (list)
Im using struct.pack() and it works well but i think this is very ugly:

```
buf = pack(">IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII", *data)
```

I need to do this because my list has 113 Items with large and small values. Is there a option to use pack() with a long list without having 113 "I"'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **multiply a string with an integer, the string is repeated that many times**. For instance:

```
>>> 'foo'*3
'foofoofoo'
```

So you can use:

```
buf = pack(">" + "I"*len(data), *data)
```

This is more elegant and safe as well: in case the number of objects changes, this will simply keep working.